# How to replace only specific 20 characters using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, command

**file.dat**

```
No      Name                       Title               Publisher           Edition

1001 Programming in Java By BPB    Balaguruswamy       BPB                 Second 
1002 Computer Networks             Tanenbaum           Pearson             Fifth
1003 Operating Systems             Chaudhari           Jaico               First
```

1. No: Numeric (4) – uniquely identifies each book
2. Title: Alphanumeric(30)
3. Author: Character(20)
4. Publisher: Character(20)
5. Edition: Character(9)

I want to replace all publishers with name `BPB` to -> `THM` **under publisher column only**. Using `sed`, it not only replaces under **Publisher** column, but also under **Name** column. I want `sed` to work only between *55th character* to *74th character*

I have extracted 55th-74th character using

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo ${line:55:20}
done < $file
```

What should I do to replace only specific 20 characters?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Fields are delimeted  by counting exact number of spaces that each column requires.

Comment: Actually I love using AWK, but this is my assignment question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

To replace the publisher column in its entirety (`BPB` followed by 17 spaces:

```
sed 's/^\(.\{55\}\)BPB\( \{17\}\)/\1THM\2/'
```

To replace the `BPB` string with `THM` wherever it appears in the publisher column:

```
sed '
  :1
    s/^\(.\{55,72\}\)BPB/\1THM/
  t1'
```